# SQL wait times on EventQueue

Tags: sql-database

Has anyone seen large wait times in SQL Server related to the Event Queue? Specifically, we are seeing `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` being reported as a problem when accessing the Event Queue in SQL Server.

We have something like 50+ servers connected to the same core database, I am wondering if the rapid querying by all boxes is causing the issue.

This is using Sitecore 8.1 u3.

Comment: What version of Sitecore are we talking about here?  EventQueue tuning options can be very version specific.

Comment: Are you using SQL Replication on the Core database?  That can cause a lot of network activity, too.

Comment: No we have a single CoreDB

Answer (score 7):

To be honest, I'm not sure if what I describe below will fix the ASYNC_NETWORK_IO issue. Seeing *NETWORK_IO* lets me think that the issue is more network or server related than being a real Sitecore issue.

However, we have also seen high loads due to `EventQueue` table activity. With the help of Sitecore Support we've come to this solution:

Clean EventQueue on CM more frequent:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <scheduling>
            <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupEventQueue, Sitecore.Kernel">
                <patch:attribute name="interval">00:30:00</patch:attribute>
                <DaysToKeep>
                    <patch:delete />
                </DaysToKeep>
                <IntervalToKeep>01:00:00</IntervalToKeep>
            </agent>
        </scheduling>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

On CD, check the EventQueue less frequent and disable the EventQueue cleanup (as it's already been taken care of by the CM):

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <eventing>
            <eventQueue>
                <processingInterval>00:02:00</processingInterval>
            </eventQueue>
        </eventing>
        <scheduling>
            <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupEventQueue, Sitecore.Kernel">
                <patch:attribute name="interval">00:00:00</patch:attribute>
            </agent>
        </scheduling>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Using these values means that published content can take up to 2 minutes before it becomes visible. But it should lower the load on the `EventQueue` table.